# Why does g++ report a function as having type int ()()?

Tags: c++, g++

```
$ cat -n cons.cpp
     1  #include <iostream>
     2
     3  using namespace std;
     4
     5  int return1() {
     6      return 1;
     7  }
     8
     9  int main() {
    10      cout<< return1.m_one << endl;
    11      return 0;
    12  }
$ g++ cons.cpp
cons.cpp: In function 'int main()':
cons.cpp:10: error: request for member 'm_one' in 'return1',
             which is of non-class type 'int ()()'
$
```

Maybe this is compiler specific, but is there some significance / meaning of the extra pair of brackets in `int ()()` as reported by g++ above?

Comment: Unless I totally misunderstand the code, you are trying to access a member of a function pointer? Hence the error. And it is reported as int()() which looks a lot like int(*)(void) , a pointer to a function which takes void and returns int. Could be wrong though, so just throwing a guess

Comment: Yes, the code is wrong and I expected an error.

Comment: In gcc (4.4.1) (C-only) the error is totally different.
error: request for member m_one in something not a structure or a union

In g++(4.4.1): I get:
|error: request for member 'm_one' in 'return1', which is of non-class type 'int()'  
So it's totally compiler specific and different between versions of the same compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of this syntax is this:

- The inner pair of brackets means *I am a function*
- The `int` on the left side means *My return type is `int`*
- The right pair of brackets means *I take no arguments*

Hence if the function had been declared as

```
int return1(int a)
```

the error message would talk about `int ()(int)`.

But the way the function type is represented indeed depends on the compiler as well as the version. E.g. GCC 4.5.1 which I just tried simply said `int()` as you suggested as more intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

A function pointer would be `int (*)()`. `int ()()` isn't legal syntax, but I can see how a type pretty printer might output it for a function type.

What this syntax would actually mean as a type declarator, if it were legal, is:

```
   function taking no arguments
    ↓↓
int ()()
↑↑↑   ↑↑
  and returning int(), i.e. a function that takes no argument and returns int.
```

But in C and C++ functions are prohibited from returning functions directly and instead must return pointers to functions. Similarly you can't return an array directly (`int ()[10]`)

The way a function's type is actually spelled doesn't have one of those sets of parentheses. This is legal when, for example, declaring the arguments and return value for `std::function`

```
               ↓↓↓↓↓
std::function< int() > foo = []() -> int { return 1; };
```

Comment: @JohanLundberg by that I mean that you can parse the statement using C++'s grammar and see what it means, but there's a rule that prohibits functions from returning another function. For example, using `std::function` to get a context requiring a type declarator: `std::function<int ()()> foo;` gives the error: `error: function cannot return function type 'int ()'`

Comment: @JohanLundberg The rule that prohibits functions from return functions or arrays is § 8.3.5 /8 in [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/#mailing2012-01)

Comment: Note that declaring functions like `int (foo)(int i)` is totally fine and often done for `min`/`max` functions to prevent macro expansion.

Answer (score 1):

on C++11 enabled compiler, `int()()` in error messages means "callable element (first `()`) taking no parameter (second `()`) returning int. (C++03 and C99 function pointers like `int(*)()` are self-dereferencing, and calling int(*)() or int(&)() is the same, hence the need to unify the message)

This is what `return1` actually is (a function *pointer or reference*). And being `int` not a "compound type", the compiler complains about the `.` and the follwing *member*.

Comment: Even in C++11 `int()()` is not legal syntax. What it would actually mean is a function that takes nothing and returns `int()` just like `int ()[]` means a function that takes nothing and returns an array of int. In C++03 as well as C++11 the type that means 'function taking nothing and returning an int' is spelled `int()`. E.g. `std::function<int()> foo = []() -> int { return 1; }`

Comment: @bames53

I din't say is "legal syntax": I said "it means" in the error message.

Legal syntax is int(*fn)() and int(&fn)(), but since the "call action" is the same for both ( fn() ) the message omits the * or &.

Sorry for not been clear. I just update the message